# Can I scan with a HP OfficeJet Pro 9018 without logging into an HP account?

Tags: privacy, scanner, hp-officejet

I bought an HP OfficeJet Pro 9018 for its duplex scanning capability.  The HP Smart scan application will not scan anything without logging into an HP account.  I absolutely do not want anything I scan to leave my LAN.  It can only go from my printer to my computer without leaving my LAN.

Is this possible with the HP 9018 (9010 series) without being logged into a HP account?

I've also tried the Windows 10 scan and fax utility.  It works, but duplex scans are done in two images, one for each side which is not what I want.

Is there any way to make a HP 9018 duplex scan without requiring internet access?  I'm open to buying a reasonably priced application if that is what it takes.

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-Copying/How-to-Scan-without-accessing-the-HP-Cloud-Services/td-p/7809647